# How can I use SKYPE with Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: skype, 17.04

I have the new version of Ubuntu on my laptop and can't install Skype again. With the older version 15.04 it was no problem to install Skype. What can I do?

Comment: http://bfy.tw/u0A

Comment: Both the [old version](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-chat-skype.html) and the [new version](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/) work on 17.04. Please describe which version you tried to install and provide details about the problem.

Comment: https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/ Download the .deb file form here and you are done

Comment: Why don't you try https://github.com/stanfieldr/ghetto-skype

Answer (score 5):

https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/

download the deb one

if it isn't installed already install gdebi :

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install gdebi
```

then `cd` to the download dirrectory and run gdebi for the downloaded deb :

```
sudo gdebi skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

you may instead just right click on the downloaded file go into propreties and set the default program to open this sort of file to gdebi (which is recommended in the meantime in 17.04) and then simply double click the file and when gdebi opens and finishes loading the file click install (you wil be prompted for password)

cheers!

Comment: I have tried "sudo gdebi –n skypeforlinux-64.deb" but got "no such file -n" and  "sudo gdebi skypeforlinux-64.deb" work.